# Как сделать проигрывание музыки в мобильной версии?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, mobile-development

Как в мобильной версии сайта можно реализовать простенький плеер песни, что то типо такого?

```
<audio id="myPlayer" controls><source src="ну тут песня" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тег аудио [вполне поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=audio) большинством мобильных браузеров.  Однако просто взять, скачать и проиграть трек чисто с помощью js Вы не сможете. Это не баг, это задуманное ограничение безопасности, чтобы владельцы мобильных устройств на трафик не попадали. Нужно обязательно дожидаться действия юзера, и способа обойти это средствами чисто js мне неизвестно.